# ~/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory - variable usage in command path

Tags: bash

```
home_path='~'
ssh-keyscan -t rsa "$EI_CI_HOST" >> "$home_path/.ssh/known_hosts"
```

Results in:

```
bash: ~/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
```

When I do the following it works though:

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa "$EI_CI_HOST" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's because `~` is not expanded and is treated as a literal `~`. Use the variable `$HOME` instead.

Comment: It'll be expanded if you don't put it in quotes. `home_path=~` would work... though using `$HOME` is indeed the better practice.

Comment: (well -- `$HOME` wouldn't be expanded either in single quotes, but if you made it double quotes `$HOME` would work, whereas `~` still wouldn't).